# Error al iniciar en MySQL en mi localhost(xampp)

Tags: mysql, xampp

me podrías ayudar a saber cual es el motivo de este error que me esta saliendo al intentar encender el MySQL en mi local y también si es que a alguien más le ha pasado, como lo pudo solucionar ¿?

InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-10  9:32:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2021-03-10  9:32:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2021-03-10  9:32:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2021-03-10  9:32:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2021-03-10  9:32:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2021-03-10  9:32:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M

2021-03-10  9:32:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2021-03-10  9:32:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2021-03-10  9:32:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2021-03-10  9:32:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2021-03-10  9:32:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2021-03-10  9:32:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 301072; transaction id 195

2021-03-10  9:32:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2021-03-10  9:32:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2021-03-10  9:32:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

De antemano les agradezco mucho por sus respuestas. ¡Saludos!

Comment: yo no veo ningun error...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi es que al momento de tratar de prenderlo eso que coloque es lo que me muestra en el error.log y esto es lo que me muestra en la consola  [mysql]  Status change detected: stopped
[mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
[mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
[mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
[mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
[mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
[mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
[mysql]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: cuando apretas para ver los logs, solo ves esto? no ves el del crash?

Comment: Correcto, solo me aparece eso, por lo mismo no se bien cual puede ser el error, ayer lo desinstale y volví a instalar y me funciono bien y hoy que lo volví a encender ya no me deja y me aparece solo eso

Answer (score 1):

Es configuración de puertos, por sino has encontrado respuesta, encontré esto y me ha funcionado:

SOLUCION : Por favor no borres el archivo ibdata1, esto podría dejar inservibles tus bases de datos.

-Antes de empezar asegúrate de cerrar procesos de XAMPP y cerrar el programa

-Cambia el nombre de la carpeta mysql/data por mysql/data_old o el nombre que desees.
-Crea una nueva carpeta mysql/data
-Copia el contenido de mysql/backup en la carpeta mysql/data
-Copia todas las carpetas de tus bases de datos de mysql/data_old a mysql/data (no copies las carpetas mysql, performance_schema, ni phpmyadmin)
-Finalmente copia el archivo ibdata1 de mysql/data_old a mysql/data.
-Inicia MySQL en el panel de control XAMPP
y listo